# Deriving an SSH Fingerprint from a Public Key in Python

Tags: python, openssh

I'm trying to understand the steps to take an OpenSSH public key like so:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAqmEmDTNBC6O8HGCdu0MZ9zLCivDsYSttrrmlq87/YsEBpvwUTiF3UEQuFLaq5Gm+dtgxJewg/UwsZrDFxzpQhCHB6VmqrbKN2hEIkk/HJvCnAmR1ehXv8n2BWw3Jlw7Z+VgWwXAH50f2HWYqTaE4qP4Dxc4RlElxgNmlDPGXw/dYBvChYBG/RvIiTz1L+pYzPD4JR54IMmTOwjcGIJl7nk1VjKvl3D8Wgp6qejv4MfZ7Htdc99SUKcKWAeHYsjPXosSk3GlwKiS/sZi51Yca394GE7T4hZu6HTaXeZoD8+IZ7AijYn89H7EPjuu0iCAa/cjVzBsFHGszQYG+U5KfIw==

And then to convert it into an standard fingerprint like so:

```
2048 49:d3:cb:f6:00:d2:93:43:a6:27:07:ca:12:fd:5d:98 id_rsa.pub (RSA)
```

I have attempted to dive into the OpenSSH source to understand this, but it is over my head.  My first guess was to do a simple MD5 on the key text, but the result does not match the above output.

Comment: The finger print isn't a direct hash of the key. You can delve into the openssh source, for ssh-keygen in particular, which has the fingerprint extraction code. Some minor details here: http://www.lysium.de/blog/index.php?/archives/186-How-to-get-ssh-server-fingerprint-information.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is the MD5 sum of the base64-encoded key:

```
import base64
import hashlib

def lineToFingerprint(line):
    key = base64.b64decode(line.strip().split()[1].encode('ascii'))
    fp_plain = hashlib.md5(key).hexdigest()
    return ':'.join(a+b for a,b in zip(fp_plain[::2], fp_plain[1::2]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful. I replaced `line.partition('ssh-rsa ')[2]` with `line.split()[2]` to handle optional OpenSSH annotations like: `ssh-rsa .....key... JohnDoe@his_laptop` that must be removed.

Comment: @Adrián You're totally right, fixed. I assume you mean `split()[1]`.

Comment: The function in this solution is equivalent to running `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -md5 -inform pem -in key.crt` on a crt or pem file.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/ojarva/sshpubkeys

`pip install sshpubkeys`

Usage:

```
import sshpubkeys
key = sshpubkeys.SSHKey("ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAqmEmDTNBC6O8H" +
    "GCdu0MZ9zLCivDsYSttrrmlq87/YsEBpvwUTiF3UEQuFLaq5Gm+dtgxJewg/UwsZrDFxz" +
    "pQhCHB6VmqrbKN2hEIkk/HJvCnAmR1ehXv8n2BWw3Jlw7Z+VgWwXAH50f2HWYqTaE4qP4" +
    "Dxc4RlElxgNmlDPGXw/dYBvChYBG/RvIiTz1L+pYzPD4JR54IMmTOwjcGIJl7nk1VjKvl" +
    "3D8Wgp6qejv4MfZ7Htdc99SUKcKWAeHYsjPXosSk3GlwKiS/sZi51Yca394GE7T4hZu6H" +
    "TaXeZoD8+IZ7AijYn89H7EPjuu0iCAa/cjVzBsFHGszQYG+U5KfIw== user@host")
print(key.bits)   # 2048
print(key.hash()) # '49:d3:cb:f6:00:d2:93:43:a6:27:07:ca:12:fd:5d:98'
```

Comment: What's interesting is that `sshpubkeys` actually refers to the other answer on this question for its implementation: https://github.com/ojarva/python-sshpubkeys/blob/master/sshpubkeys/keys.py#L126

Comment: warnings.warn("hash() is deprecated. Use hash_md5(), hash_sha256() or hash_sha512() instead.")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you have a public key object using the `cryptography` library, that gives a SHA256 fingerprint (the new preferred choice.)

It took a lot of troubleshooting to find the right set of bytes to fingerprint to match the fingerprint given by `ssh-keygen -l`. You have to first format the public key in OpenSSH style, then decode the base 64 encoded bytes from that formatted style, and hash those - just hashing the raw bytes won't work.

```py
import base64

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization


def get_public_key_fingerprint(public_key):
    formatted = public_key.public_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH,
        format=serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH,
    )
    parts = formatted.split(b" ")
    key_bytes = base64.b64decode(parts[1])

    digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA256())
    digest.update(key_bytes)
    fingerprint = base64.b64encode(digest.finalize()).rstrip(b"=").decode("utf-8")

    return f"SHA256:{fingerprint}"
```